# RabbitMQ consume one message if exists and quit

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp

I am running code on python to send and receive from RabbitMQ queue from another application where I can't allow threading. 
This is very newbie question but, is there a possibility to just check if there is message and if there are no any then just quit listening ? How should I change basic "Hello world" example for such task? Currently I've managed to stop consuming if I get a message, but if there are no messages my method receive() just continue waiting. How to force it not to wait if there are no messages? Or maybe wait only for given amount of time?

```
import pika

global answer

def send(msg):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters())
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='toJ')
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='toJ', body=msg)
    connection.close()

def receive():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='toM')
    channel.basic_consume(callback, queue='toM', no_ack=True)
    global answer
    return answer

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    ch.stop_consuming()
    global answer
    answer = body
```

Comment: the ruby API has a method to check the length of the queue.. have you checked the python docs?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ok, I found following solution:

```
def receive():
    parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(RabbitMQ_server)
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='toM')
    method_frame, header_frame, body = channel.basic_get(queue = 'toM')        
    if method_frame.NAME == 'Basic.GetEmpty':
        connection.close()
        return ''
    else:            
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method_frame.delivery_tag)
        connection.close() 
        return body
```

Comment: Should also be important to check if method_frame is None. If there are no further messages in the queue, the channel.basic_get(queue = 'toM') will return with None-s.

Comment: @GrayR Is there any way to do this and acknowledge the message after completion?

Comment: `method_frame.NAME` does not seem to exist for pika >0.10.0. Simply testing for
`if method_frame is None:` works fine with pika 1.1.0